# cannot load such file -- 2.2/gherkin_lexer_en, how to fix?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, calabash, calabash-android

I need a little help. How do I resolve this problem?

When I call `cucumber` I get the following error:

```
  *** WARNING: You must use ANSICON 1.31 or higher (https://github.com/adoxa/ansic
on/) to get coloured output on Windows
WARNING: cannot load such file -- 2.2/gherkin_lexer_en
Couldn't load 2.2/gherkin_lexer_en
The $LOAD_PATH was:
lib
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cucumber-1.3.19/bin/../lib
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/builder-3.2.2/lib
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/diff-lcs-1.2.5/lib
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/multi_json-1.11.0/lib
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/gherkin-2.12.2-x86-mingw32/lib
[...]
```

System:

- Windows 8.1 x64
- Ruby 2.2.1 installer

I got answer:
https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/issues/830#issuecomment-90837546

> I'm afraid Cucumber on Windows/Ruby requires ruby 2.0.0 (x86). The
>   reason is that the gherkin gem doesn't yet ship with compiled binaries
>   for more recent versions or Ruby, and not for x64.
>
> We're working on a Gherkin3 which will address this issue. See this
>   post for background. I cannot give you an ETA, but it's at least a few
>   months away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I download Ruby 2.0 x86 from http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/
- Install exe
- Command in cmd: `gem install calabash-android`
- `ERROR:  Error installing calabash-android:
      The 'json' native gem requires installed build tools.`
- Download from http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/ DevKit-mingw64-32-4.7.2-20130224-1151-sfx.exe
- Extract DevKit to path C:\Ruby200\DevKit
- Run cd C:\Ruby200\DevKit
- Run ruby dk.rb init
- Run ruby dk.rb review
- Run ruby dk.rb install
- And again use command `gem install calabash-android`

Comment: Thank you, downgrading from 2.2 to 2.0 worked. Thank you for the detailed instructions, I did exactly as you said.

Answer (score 0):

I have simply solved by removing `Gherkin` and reinstalling it by `bundle install`

```
gem uninstall gherkin
>> select all
bundle install
```

Answer (score -1):

This problem looks like [this issue](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/issues/519). Maybe you can resolve by following comments in it. (y)

> sanjaykumar5115 commented,
>   my probelm have been solved after uninstalling gherkin and installing gherkin-2.12.1-x86-mingw32

Comment: There sanjaykumar5115 only update gherkin-2.12.0-x86-mingw32 to gherkin-2.12.1-x86-mingw32, in my gems there is gherkin-2.12.2-x86-mingw32 i can't update higher :/

Comment: Opss, Then leave your comment in git issue. Maybe they can help you.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: @davidpostill, updated the answer and added essential.