# error installing calabash android on windows

Tags: android, ruby, cucumber, calabash, calabash-android

i'm trying to install calabash by running this command:

```
gem install calabash-android
```

- i'm running windows 8.1
- i have installed ruby 2.0.0 x86 and dev tools according to the instructions in the accepted answer here:
  [cannot load such file -- 2.2/gherkin_lexer_en, how to fix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29507570/cannot-load-such-file-2-2-gherkin-lexer-en-how-to-fix)

i'm still getting this error:

```
Fetching: builder-3.2.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed builder-3.2.2
Fetching: diff-lcs-1.2.5.gem (100%)
Successfully installed diff-lcs-1.2.5
Fetching: multi_json-1.11.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed multi_json-1.11.2
Fetching: gherkin-2.12.2-x86-mingw32.gem (100%)
Successfully installed gherkin-2.12.2-x86-mingw32
Fetching: multi_test-0.1.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed multi_test-0.1.2
Fetching: cucumber-1.3.20.gem (100%)
Successfully installed cucumber-1.3.20
Fetching: json-1.8.3.gem (100%)
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
creating Makefile
      0 [main] make 4044 handle_exceptions: Exception: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION
  73797 [main] make 4044 open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to make.exe.stackdump
MSYS-1.0.17 Build:2011-04-24 23:39
Exception: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION at eip=10002840
eax=00000000 ebx=00000000 ecx=7554CDF7 edx=001A0000 esi=00000024 edi=00000001
ebp=0028D5F8 esp=0028D460 program=C:\Ruby200\DevKit\bin\make.exe
cs=0023 ds=002B es=002B fs=0053 gs=002B ss=002B
Stack trace:
Frame     Function  Args
0028D5F8  10002840  (0028E6B0, 00000000, 6089E54C, 6089E54C)
0028EA18  6085BDBC  (00000000, 0028EA80, 10075700, 10075560)
0028EA48  6085CDB6  (00000000, 00000003, 0028EA80, 10075700)
0028EA68  6080E236  (0028EA80, 10075700, 00000000, 00000000)
0028EE98  60882726  (100757B0, 10075700, 0041C410, 10060178)
0028EEC8  0040ECAE  (10075700, 10075560, 10075700, 10075560)
0028EF38  0040E157  (10075538, 000000C8, 0028EF68, 00404E71)
0028EF68  0040E230  (10075538, 10071200, 10074F80, 00000006)
0028EFE8  0040E5EA  (10071200, 00000000, 00000000, 00000000)
0028F058  004193EA  (10071200, 00000004, 00000000, 00000003)
0028F078  004189AD  (10071200, 00000004, 10070FE0, 10071180)
0028F0B8  00419E28  (10071200, 00000003, 00000001, 00000000)
0028F128  00418CE6  (100710E8, 00000002, 00000000, 00000001)
0028F148  004189AD  (100710E8, 00000002, 00000011, 10070FE0)
0028F188  00419E28  (100710E8, 00000001, 00000001, 00000000)
0028F1F8  00418CE6  (1006CFD8, 00000000, 00000000, 1006CFD8)
End of stack trace (more stack frames may be present)
```

any idea what i'm still doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any non-ascii characters in your %PATH% or %TEMP% system variables?
Correct this and try once more.

Or you can try to install gem with --platform=ruby parameter.
And one more variant - install json-pure, to avoid compiling.

(usually installing devkit finishes with installing json - try once more time)